# Android Intent Activity Logic?

Tags: android, android-intent

learning about `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);`

**LEGENDS:**

**x-->**  finish(); after startActivity(Intent);

**<--x-->** finish(); after startActivity(Intent); AND if back button is pressed finish() this and created a startActivity(Intent) going back

**-->** startActivity(Intent) not finished

**------------------------**

Here's my diagram:

A **x-->** B **<--x-->** C **<--x-->** D **-->** E **x-->** F

on F Activity, there is a RETRY AND EXIT BUTTON.
If retryButton is pressed, finish F Activity which will result back to D Activity since it is not finished.

**PROBLEM**

If exitButton is pressed, finish ActivityF and NEW intent.startActivity(ActivityC);

Because ActivityC is a new Intent, it becomes the TOP ACTIVITY and FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP won't do anything.

The thing is I also want to finish ActivityD so that when I reach ActivityB and press the back button it ask me if I want to quit the program, if yes then finish() ActivityB...

when I do that, however, ActivityD is still on. Because of this ActivityD has a potential of overstacking and might be bad for the memory( I suppose?)

Anyway to close ActivityD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the ans. I have the same situation... try this solution. This will clear all your top activities from stack.

```
Intent i = new Intent(mContext,LoginActivity_IDY.class);
                    i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_ANIMATION  );
                    overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.slide_right);
                    startActivity(i);
                    finish();
```

Comment: Nicely Done! I put this on the exitButton... well actually just the setFlags line and it work... I have yet to understand overridePending but thats another topic for another day.. you get a check, ser!

Comment: overridePendingTransition(0, R.anim.slide_right); 

this line used for exit animation. Like when your activity finish then it animate from left to right.